# CS6 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: void

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
stop();



button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gobutton1);
function button1_clicked(e:MouseEvent):viod{
        gotoAndStop("page1");
}

button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gobutton2);
function button2_clicked(e:MouseEvent):viod{
        gotoAndStop("page2");
}

button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gobutton3);
function button3_clicked(e:MouseEvent):viod{
        gotoAndStop("page3");
}

button4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gobutton4);
function button4_clicked(e:MouseEvent):viod{
        gotoAndStop("page4");
}
```

im getting a 1046 error its about line 7,12,17 and 22 I got a web page in flash and it                                             keeps flashing on a loop

Comment: It is in cs6 and ive used this for help but somewhere along the line i went wrong

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Qn3mDxDqQ1o#t=211s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spelled `void` wrong at the end of all your function definitions.

```
function button1_clicked(e:MouseEvent):viod
// -------------------------------------^^
```